# The selection of specific columns in SQLAlchemy in scalars does not work

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

When writing a query with specific columns in select, I get only the first element that I specified in it. That is, such a code

```
query = select(self.model.name, self.model.price).join(CategoryRepository.model).join(
ImageRepository.model, is outer=True)
```

```
print((await self._session.scalars(query)).all())
```

Returns `['Shoes', 'Dress', 'Pendant']` - only the names, although the sql code generates the correct one. And when calling execute, everything works correctly

```
print((await self._session.execute(query)).all())
```

Returns `[('Dress', 350.0199890136719), ('Shoes', 300.04998779296875), ('Pendant', 99.98999786376953)]`

Comment: What exactly do you expect? `scalars()` means that SQLAlchemy should only return one python object per database row, instead of a `Row` object (basically a tuple) per row.